# MYSQL order by - to follow a pattern

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How can we set up patterns for results to be either selected or saved in a variable.

so basically when i select data it is ordered like the following.

```
customer ID               Email
1                         test@gmail.com
2                         test@hotmail.com
3                         test@yahoo.com
4                         test@seznam.cz
```

So I want to select all records in table! however I want to order them so they follow this format

```
customer ID               Email
1                         test@gmail.com
2                         test@hotmail.com
3                         test@yahoo.com
4                         test@seznam.cz
52                        test2@gmail.com
7                         test2@hotmail.com
84                        test2@yahoo.com
99                        test2@seznam.cz
10                        test3@gmail.com
11                        test3@hotmail.com
124                       test3@yahoo.com
1321                      test3@seznam.cz
```

SO how can I set up my query to get my results to follow a similar order. I basically want to know how I can select (or deal with once its stored) the data from my database to follow a certain pattern.

EDIT:

this is the script i am trying, it does work partly however the data does not stick to the pattern.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, email
FROM customer_1_tbl
WHERE customer_id IN (
    SELECT cust.customer_id 
    FROM customer_1_binding_tbl AS cust 
    WHERE cust.mailinglist_id = '2') order by substring_index(email, '@', 1),
     (case substring_index(email, '@', -1)
          when ('gmail.com' or 'hotmail.com' or 'jednotavimperk.cz') then 1
          when ('seznam.cz' or 'email.cz' or 'post.cz') then 2
          when 'tiscali.cz' then 3
          when ('centrum.cz' or 'atlas.cz' or 'volny.cz') then 4
          else 999
      end)
```

Comment: What is the pattern that defines the ordering?

Comment: the email domain. for example first gmail, yahoo, seznam..then repeat until all the emails have been ordered like this. @GordonLinoff

Comment: You can use MySQL [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) exp: `HAVING email REGEXP '[a-z]' ORDER BY email DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the `email` column apart.  Then, use a `case` to assign the ordering priority:

```
order by substring_index(email, '@', 1),
         (case substring_index(email, '@', -1)
              when 'gmail.com' then 1
              when 'hotmail.com' then 2
              when 'yahoo.com' then 3
              when 'seznam.cz' then 4
              else 999
          end)
```

Another handy function for this is `field()`.  But, it doesn't give you the easy option of an `else` clause, for non-matches.

EDIT:

Your edited code is just wrong.  That is not how you express multiple conditions in a `case`.  Try this:

```
order by substring_index(email, '@', 1),
         (case when substring_index(email, '@', -1) in ('gmail.com', 'hotmail.com', 'jednotavimperk.cz') then 1
               when substring_index(email, '@', -1) in ('seznam.cz', 'email.cz', 'post.cz') then 2
               when substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'tiscali.cz' then 3
               when substring_index(email, '@', -1) in ('centrum.cz', 'atlas.cz', 'volny.cz') then 4
               else 999
          end)
```

Comment: No that does not work. it leaves a really unusal order however it has nothing to do with the pattern.

Comment: @invincible.superman . . . Set up a SQL Fiddle.  This seems to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: but the problem I got is it does not stick to that order. especially with the scale of email address i have...i have edited my comment to show you what i am using. @gordonLinoff

Comment: Your `case` statement looks nothing like mine.  I would suggest that you fix it.